# Catching stripe errors using middleware and logging

Tags: node.js, express, stripe-payments

I'm curious if there's a good way to handle this with express 4.0.

There are times where there is a problem with either Stripe, or my connection to Stripe that needs to be addressed. However, I obviously do not want users to know about this. I want to display a message `'There was a problem completing your order, please contact support.'` while safely logging the message with some information for me to handle it.

I suspect I can do this in middleware. However, I'm not sure how. I would like to catch these errors as they are happening and dump them to a logfile of some kind (suggestions would be great) so I can handle it.

Is there a standard way of doing this? How would I accomplish this?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You're thinking about this the wrong way. Instead of exposing 3rd party errors, explicitly define each possible failure case in your route.

```
// bad

app.use(function (err, req, res, next) {
  res.status(err.status).json({ error: err.message }) 
})
```

Instead mark errors to be exposed:

```
app.use(function (err, req, res, next) {
  if (err.expose) {
    res.status(err.status).json({ code: err.code, error: err.message })
  } else {
    reportError(err, req)
    res.status(500).json({ code: "unknown", error: "unknown error" })
  }
})
```

You need to re-throw actual api errors.

```
function createError(status, message) {
  var err = new Error(message)
  err.expose = true
  err.status = status
  return err
}

function changeCard(user, data) {
  return postStripeCards(user, data)
  .catch({ type: "card_error" }, function (err) {
    throw createError(400, "invalid card")
  }) 
}
```

Uncaught errors are programmer mistakes which should be reported and fixed. Anything that makes it through is a bug.

```
function reportError (err, req) {
  // log error
  console.error(err.stack)

  // send to rollbar
  rollbar.handleError(err, req)

  // maybe send an email
  mailgun.send({
    from: "bot@myapp.com",
    to: "me@gmail.com",
    subject: "My App: " + err.message,
    text: err.stack + "\n\n" + JSON.stringify(req),
  })

  // pager duty, airbrake, etc
}
```

It takes work, but it means your API is well-defined.